# Restore Qt Window size and position problem

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I save and restore a QMainWindow's size and position as follows:

```
window->resize(savedSize);
window->move(savedPos);
window->show();

void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e) {
    savedSize = window->size();
    savedPos = window->pos();
}
```

The problem is that the window position is changed by the applications bar (the bar where the Windows minimize and maximize buttons are). So when I open and close the window a few times then the window moves more and more down (each time exactly the size of the application bar). How can I exactly restore the last position?

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

You should use [QWidget::saveGeometry()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#saveGeometry) to get the window size and  [QWidget::restoreGeometry()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#restoreGeometry) to restore it, for instance with QSetting. You may be interested also in [QMainWindow::saveState() and QMainWindow::restoreState()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#restoreState)

Comment: The docs also state that we can use resize() and pos() instead but I will check if saveGeometry() correctly keeps the position.